# Why does this give the same result with the same number of iterations?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, algorithms, roots, inverse

$$f(x)=x^4+2x^3+5x^2+5x-3$$
For this function, I used inverse quadratic interpolation and interestingly with 2 fixed points and 1 arbitrary, the algorithm always gave me the same result with the same number of iterations.

Two points I've chosen are: $(-1+2i, f(-1+2i)), (-0.5+2i, f(-0.5+2i))$

It does not matter what point you choose for the third one, it always gives you the same non-real root with the same number of iterations. Why does this happen? Is it because those two points are already close enough to the root?

Just realised that it gives the same root with different number of iterations if third point's $|x|$ is too small.

Comment: @Moo inverse quadratic interpolation, as it is.

Comment: @Moo Sorry, I mean I don't have any formula for it. I used the given points and any third one, then by using Lagrange interpolation formula, found the quadratic equation and took inverse of it. Finally used that $x$ value where the inverse parabola intersects $x$-axis as the new $x$ value and repeated the process.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are not using inverse quadratic interpolation, but rather inverting a quadratic interpolation. Overall it is not clear what you are doing, so you should write it out in the question how exactly you are doing what you are doing, possibly with an example.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt what's difference between what I do and  what inverse quadratic interpolation?

Comment: Inverse quadratic interpolation is interpolating with $x=q(y)$, where $q$ is a quadratic. The estimated root is then simply $x=q(0)$. So we aren't finding a quadratic and taking the inverse of this, but rather inverting the points and finding the quadratic.

Comment: Again, you should be more specific about your steps by editing your question. Until then I cannot tell you much more about what you are doing.